# GitHub does not let me to access subfolder in remote repo

Tags: reactjs, git, spring-boot, github

Im developing a full stack application that consist of a springbok api & React UI. The api is developed in IntelliJ, while I work on the react UI in VS code. For some reason , i'm unable to access the react portion of my application in its GitHub remote repository after I pushed from my local. Please, see the attached image for how I'm unable to access the src/js folder in GitHub which contains my react code.

I'll appreciate any input on how I can best resolve this issue , so that I can access the react code in the js folder. [Link to Github Page](https://github.com/logunlaja26/springboot-amigos-code/tree/master/src)

[image]

Comment: it does not seem a normal file present in the repository instead of an sub-module please check how can you access provided that must be accessible.

Comment: edit the question with information showing what is in the directory on your PC. Based on the answers from the duplicate question, it could be a number of things...

Comment: @silentsudo thanks ! I was able to resolve the issue. I had mistakenly initialized git in my js directory and root directory as well